# Is this sentence correct to ask for a go

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I have to ask a customer, if I can proceed with my work and I set up this sentence:

*Please tell me if I should proceed.*

Is this correct or is there a better way?

Comment: Can you describe the "scene" a bit? What's going on?

Comment: I present my work to a customer. He checked the work. Now I need only the final _go_. I know, I can proceed. But I have to wait (next step is publish my work).

Comment: It looks fine to me. You can use comma after the "introductory element" if you want. _"Please, tell me if I should proceed."_

Comment: We say *the go-ahead*. *I'm still waiting for the go-ahead on that job they contacted me about last week*. A *go* by itself has other meanings, e.g. *let me have a go* = *let me have a turn*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a more formal way you might want to say: "May I proceed?"